# Onde conseguir livros online seguindo o Novo Acordo Ortográfico?

Tags: ortografia, acordo-ortográfico, literatura

Estou estudando para concursos públicos e gosto muito de ler. Infelizmente todos meus livros em português que possuo em casa tem >6 anos de idade, logo não estão de acordo com o Novo Acordo Ortografico. Eu sei que o excelente website Domínio Publico oferece milhares de títulos gratuitamente, mas não sei como filtrar apenas por resultados que estejam de acordo com a nova ortografia.

Por favor, alguém me indicaria um local online para conseguir textos, de preferência dentre as obras clássicas brasileiras, que estejam de acordo com as novas regras gramaticais?

Comment: Não existe nova ortografia brasileira. A nova ortografia é do português: "O novo acordo ortográfico foi realizado em 2009, com prazo de adaptação até 2012, e visa uniformizar e aproximar a gramática entre os 9 países que têm a Língua Portuguesa como língua oficial." As mudanças consistem principalmente na acentuação, uso no hífen, uso do trema e no alfabeto, exemplificadas a seguir. https://www.concursosnobrasil.com.br/escola/portugues/nova-ortografia-principais-mudancas.html

Comment: Creio que que te referes ao dominiopubico.gov.br. Não me parece que haja como filtrar, mas podes sempre perguntar-lhes. Imagino que obras na nova ortografia sejam raras lá: seria preciso que eles tivesse obtido digititalizações recentes de edições recentes. Eu espreitei umas tantas obras lá, e muitas nem incluem o ano da edição. Há uma maneira, obra a obra, de ver qual é a grafia: baixas o ficheiro e fazes um Ctrl F de "eia", e se encontrares "idéia, estréia", etc. é grafia antiga; esta é capaz de ser a mudança mais comum no Brasil; também há o "oo", "vôo, enjôo" antes, "voo, enjoo" agora.

Comment: Não é para te desanimar, mas suspeito que digitalizações dos clássicos estejam em todo o lado praticamente todas na grafia antiga. Nas edições em papel, aqui em Portugal, a ficha técnica do livro tende a dizer quando está na grafia antiga.

Comment: @Jacinto Verdade. O melhor que consegui foram algumas edições mais recentes pela LibGen.io mas há muito poucas. Infelizmente o Domínio Público não tem a funcionalidade de filtrar por ano de edições...